# CSS Center nav bar links

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

Having trouble centering some text links on my nav bar, margin left and right auto aren't working and i've tried setting display types to block/inline-block to no avail. The solution is probably staring me in the face I know but I really can't find it.

CSS:

```
.navmenu {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    background-image: url("../images/NavBar.gif");
    background-position: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #383838;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    z-index:105;
}
.navlink {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navmenu">
    <div class="navlink">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="http://twitch.tv/" target="_blank">Twitch</a>
        <a href="http://youtube.com/" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
        <a href="teamspeak.php">Teamspeak</a>
        <a href="/forum/">Forum</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex to it get more flexible:

```
.navmenu { margin: 0 auto }
.navlink { display: flex; justify-content: center }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting `.navlink` `width` to `100%`.  Reduce it to the width of the rest of your content.  I tried `800px` and it worked well.

Comment: this seems like the right solution based on the problem to me. the page should hold together much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-menu{ width: 100%; text-align: center; }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You following CSS on .navlink

```
 .navlink {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.navmenu {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    border-top: 1px solid #383838;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    z-index:105;
}
.navlink {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

.navlink a {
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="navmenu">
    <div class="navlink">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="http://twitch.tv/" target="_blank">Twitch</a>
        <a href="http://youtube.com/" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
        <a href="teamspeak.php">Teamspeak</a>
        <a href="/forum/">Forum</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i have a another very good solution for you

```
<div id="nav">
    <span><a href="#">Twitter</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Facebook</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">YouTube</a></span>
</div>


<!--Css style sheet for above code-->
#nav{
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
}
#nav span a{
   text-decoration:none;
   padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add `text-align:center;` to your `nav-link` class

```
.nav-link
{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
.navlink { text-align:center }
```

Comment: Cheers, knew it would be something stupidly simple, always overthink everything.

Comment: While this will work, be aware that it may look odd when you shrink the page too thin.

Answer (score -2):

The top logo is centered because it has a fixed width.  The nav bar is not centered because it is 100% of the screen width.  If you make this a lower percent or use the same fixed width as the logo image, then it will work be centered.

```
.navlink {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1024px;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: hmm I fixed it with text-align center but i'll keep this in mind cheers.

Comment: I dont know why this was voted down.  The nav bar has an image that  has a fixed width and this cannot be scaled down.